# Problem with siunitx package dependencies

Tags: siunitx, texlive-2020

Yesterday I was using the `siunitx` package to do some homework and it worked fine. Today, I was working on the same document and, for some reason that idk, TeXstudio started to throw close to 100 errors related to the `siunitx` and `expl3` packages. Some of the notable ones are:

> ​! Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old.
>
> Can be used only in preamble. {A comprehensive (SI) units package}

Idk what happenned. I reinstalled my TeX Live distribution, and the error still persists. What do I do?

I using the 2020 version of TeX Live and  the `siunitx` package is in version 2.8b.

I would be glad if someone could help me, as this package is really useful for my work.

Here's a MWE (That I think is not going to help, but anyway):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    hihi
\end{document}
```

**EDIT-1**: Just noticed something. For some reason, using the terminal instead of a LaTeX editor to compile the file gives me no errors.

**EDIT-2**: Log file (part of it):

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
! Undefined control sequence.
l.82   \bool
            _new:N \g__expl_reload_bool
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.82   \bool_
             new:N \g__expl_reload_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.82   \bool_new:N \g
                     __expl_reload_bool
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.82   \bool_new:N \g__
                       expl_reload_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \tl
        _if_exist:NF \c__expl_def_ext_tl

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 84.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.84 \tl_if_exist:NF \c_
                        _expl_def_ext_tl
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.84 \tl_if_exist:NF \c_
                        _expl_def_ext_tl
! Undefined control sequence.
l.85   { \tl
            _const:Nn \c__expl_def_ext_tl { def } }

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 85.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.85   { \tl_const:Nn \c_
                         _expl_def_ext_tl { def } }
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.85   { \tl_const:Nn \c_
                         _expl_def_ext_tl { def } }
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.85 ...\tl_const:Nn \c__expl_def_ext_tl { def } }
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
l.86 \cs
        _gset_protected:Npn \__kernel_sys_configuration_load:n #1
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.86 ...d:Npn \__kernel_sys_configuration_load:n #
                                                  1
! Undefined control sequence.
l.89     \cs
            _undefine:c { ver@ #1 .def }
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.89     \cs_undefine:c { ver@ #
                                1 .def }
! Argument of \@onefilewithoptions has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.93   }
        
Runaway argument?
 ] [ ] \c __expl_def_ext_tl \ExplSyntaxOn 
! Paragraph ended before \@onefilewithoptions was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.93   }
        
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.93   }
        
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.93   }
        
! Undefined control sequence.
l.94 \cs
        _gset_protected:Npn \__kernel_sys_configuration_load_std:n #1
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.94 ...n \__kernel_sys_configuration_load_std:n #
                                                  1
! Undefined control sequence.
l.96     \cs
            _undefine:c { ver@ #1 .def }
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.96     \cs_undefine:c { ver@ #
                                1 .def }
! Argument of \@onefilewithoptions has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.99   }
        
Runaway argument?
 ] [ ] \c __expl_def_ext_tl 
! Paragraph ended before \@onefilewithoptions was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.99   }
        
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.99   }
        
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.99   }
        
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.99   }
        
! Undefined control sequence.
l.100 \clist
            _if_exist:NF \l__expl_options_clist

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 100.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.100 \clist_if_exist:NF \l__
                             expl_options_clist
! Undefined control sequence.
l.101   { \clist
                _new:N \l__expl_options_clist }

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 101.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.101   { \clist_new:N \l__
                           expl_options_clist }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.105 \keys
           _define:nn { sys }
! Double subscript.
l.105 \keys_
            define:nn { sys }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.109       { \sys
                  _load_backend:n {#1} } ,
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.109       { \sys_load_backend:n {#
                                    1} } ,
! Undefined control sequence.
l.112         \sys
                  _load_debug:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.113         \debug
                    _on:n { check-declarations }
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.115     driver .meta:n = { backend = #
                                        1 } ,
! Undefined control sequence.
l.117       \sys
                _load_debug: ,
! Undefined control sequence.
l.120         \sys
                  _load_debug:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.121         \debug
                    _on:n { log-functions }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.124       = \g
                __kernel_backend_header_bool ,
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.124       = \g__
                  kernel_backend_header_bool ,
! Undefined control sequence.
l.128         \bool
                   _gset_true:N \g__kernel_deprecation_undo_recent_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.128         \bool_gset_true:N \g
                                  __kernel_deprecation_undo_recent_bool
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.128         \bool_gset_true:N \g__
                                    kernel_deprecation_undo_recent_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.129         \sys
                  _load_deprecation:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.132 \cs
         _if_exist:NF \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.132 \cs_if_exist:NF \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
                                               
! Undefined control sequence.
l.134     \tl
             _put_left:Nn \document
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.134     \tl_put_left:Nn \document
                                   
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(/home/joao/test.aux)
Overfull \hbox (1788.17528pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 77--134
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2020-10-05expl3.sty$[]\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ew \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 : \
OML/cmm/m/it/10 N[]$ 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.136         \endgroup
                       
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.136         \endgroup
                       
! Undefined control sequence.
l.137         \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
                                       
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.139       }
             
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.140   }
         
! Undefined control sequence.
l.141 \cs
         _gset_protected:Npn \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.141 \cs_
          gset_protected:Npn \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.141 ...t_protected:Npn \@expl@sys@load@backend@@
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
l.143     \str
              _if_exist:NF \c_sys_backend_str

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 143.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.143     \str_if_exist:NF \c_
                              sys_backend_str
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.143     \str_if_exist:NF \c_
                              sys_backend_str
! Undefined control sequence.
l.144       { \sys
                  _load_backend:n { } }
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.145   }
         
! Undefined control sequence.
l.146 \keys
           _set:nV { sys } \l__expl_options_clist

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 146.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.146 \keys_set:nV { sys } \l__
                               expl_options_clist
! Undefined control sequence.
l.147 \str
          _if_exist:NF \c_sys_backend_str

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 147.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.147 \str_if_exist:NF \c_
                          sys_backend_str
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.147 \str_if_exist:NF \c_
                          sys_backend_str
! Undefined control sequence.
l.148   { \sys
              _load_backend:n { } }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.149 \bool
           _if:NT \g__expl_reload_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.149 \bool_if:NT \g
                    __expl_reload_bool
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.149 \bool_if:NT \g__
                      expl_reload_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.151     \cs
             _gset_eq:NN \__kernel_sys_configuration_load:n
! Undefined control sequence.
l.154     \file
               _input_stop:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.156 \cs
         _if_free:cTF { ver@expl3.sty }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.158     \tex
              _everyjob:D \exp_after:wN
! Undefined control sequence.
l.160         \tex
                  _the:D \tex_everyjob:D
! Undefined control sequence.
l.160         \tex_the:D \tex
                             _everyjob:D
! Undefined control sequence.
l.161         \sys
                  _everyjob:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.164   { \sys
              _everyjob: }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.165 \reverse
              _if:N \if_cs_exist:N \s__expl_stop
! Undefined control sequence.
l.168 \cs
         _if_exist:NF \@expl@push@filename@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.168 \cs_if_exist:NF \@expl@push@filename@@
                                            
! Undefined control sequence.
l.170     \tl
             _put_left:Nn  \@pushfilename { \@expl@push@filename@@ }

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.170     \tl_put_left:Nn  \@pushfilename
                                          { \@expl@push@filename@@ }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.170 ...  \@pushfilename { \@expl@push@filename@@
                                                   }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.171     \tl
             _put_right:Nn \@pushfilename { \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ }

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.171     \tl_put_right:Nn \@pushfilename
                                          { \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 ...pushfilename { \@expl@push@filename@aux@@
                                                   }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.173 \cs
         _gset_protected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.173 ...gset_protected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@@
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
l.177         \tl
                 _to_str:N \@currname .
! Undefined control sequence.
l.178         \tl
                 _to_str:N \@currext
! Undefined control sequence.
l.180     \tl
             _put_left:Nx \l__expl_status_stack_tl

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 180.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.180     \tl_put_left:Nx \l__
                              expl_status_stack_tl
! Undefined control sequence.
l.182         \bool
                   _if:NTF \l__kernel_expl_bool

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 182.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.182         \bool_if:NTF \l__
                               kernel_expl_bool
! Undefined control sequence.
l.188 \cs
         _gset_protected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ #1#2#3
! Undefined control sequence.
l.188 ..._protected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@aux@@
                                                   #1#2#3
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.188 ...rotected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ #
                                                  1#2#3
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.188 ...tected:Npn \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ #1#
                                                  2#3
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.188 ...cted:Npn \@expl@push@filename@aux@@ #1#2#
                                                  3
! Undefined control sequence.
l.190     \str
              _gset:Nn \g_file_curr_name_str {#3}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.190     \str_gset:Nn \g
                         _file_curr_name_str {#3}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.190     \str_gset:Nn \g_file_curr_name_str {#
                                               3}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.191     #
           1 #2 {#3}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.191     #1 #
              2 {#3}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.191     #1 #2 {#
                  3}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.193 \cs
         _if_exist:NF \@expl@pop@filename@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.193 \cs_if_exist:NF \@expl@pop@filename@@
                                           
! Undefined control sequence.
l.195     \tl
             _put_right:Nn \@popfilename

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.195     \tl_put_right:Nn \@popfilename
                                        
! Undefined control sequence.
l.196       { \@expl@pop@filename@@
                                    }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.198 \cs
         _gset_protected:Npn \@expl@pop@filename@@
! Undefined control sequence.
l.198 \cs_gset_protected:Npn \@expl@pop@filename@@
                                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
l.201     \tl
             _if_empty:NTF \l__expl_status_stack_tl

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 201.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.201     \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__
                               expl_status_stack_tl

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 203.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.203 ...{ \exp_after:wN \__expl_status_pop:w \l__
                                                  expl_status_stack_tl \s__e...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.203 ..._status_pop:w \l__expl_status_stack_tl \s
                                                  __expl_stop }
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.203 ...tatus_pop:w \l__expl_status_stack_tl \s__
                                                  expl_stop }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.205 \cs
         _gset_protected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #1#2 \s__expl_stop
! Double subscript.
l.205 \cs_
          gset_protected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #1#2 \s__expl_stop
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.205 ...gset_protected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #
                                                  1#2 \s__expl_stop
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.205 ...et_protected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #1#
                                                  2 \s__expl_stop
! Undefined control sequence.
l.205 ...rotected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #1#2 \s
                                                  __expl_stop
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.205 ...tected:Npn \__expl_status_pop:w #1#2 \s__
                                                  expl_stop
! Undefined control sequence.
l.207     \tl
             _set:Nn \l__expl_status_stack_tl {#2}

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 207.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.207     \tl_set:Nn \l__
                         expl_status_stack_tl {#2}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.207     \tl_set:Nn \l__expl_status_stack_tl {#
                                                2}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.208     \int_if_odd:nTF {#
                            1}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.212 \tl
         _if_exist:NF \l__expl_status_stack_tl
! Double subscript.
l.212 \tl_
          if_exist:NF \l__expl_status_stack_tl

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 212.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.212 \tl_if_exist:NF \l__
                          expl_status_stack_tl
! Undefined control se
```

**Last Edit**: Turns out there is some TeX Live 2019 instalation somewhere in my machine and the LaTeX editors are looking for the files from that installation. So I need to find this installation and delete every file corresponding to it.

Comment: show the log-file of the MWE (this will be *very* useful).

Comment: OK. One moment, please

Comment: you will have an old copy of expl3.sty in your local tex inputs that is hiding the one installed with the texlive update

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't seem to find any copy of expl3.sty besides the one from 2020-10-05 ( I'm assuming that is october 5th of 2020)...

Comment: it's not a question of which version you find, so much as which version tex found, which was why Ulrike asked you to show your log file in the first comment

Comment: despite your comment in the question, a MWE almost always helps. In this case if you showed the log for that known input it will be easy to debug what is wrong with your intsallation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle got it! But the logfile has over 1600 lines, and I can't fit in the 30000 characters limit. I 'll see what I can do to have you guys to see the logfile

Comment: If I run the MWE your post above I get a log of 159 lines. Do you really get 16000 lines from that example????  when you get to the first error type x to stop it there is no point going past an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just edited the question

Comment: your edit-1 is misleading, an editor never processes the file it just calls a shell in the background, and runs the same latex as the terminal. So if you get different results most likely you have two latex formats installed and your editor is using an incorrectly configured one. Again the log file will show the issue. compare the log files from the working and non working versions,

Comment: OK @DavidCarlisle . I'll do this. Thank you